# Even Change With 15 Coins Probability Problem

Tags: probability

Cecil has a 15 coin collection. Four coins are quarters, seven coins are dimes, three are nickels and one is a penny.  For each scenario, calculate the total possible outcomes if Cecil randomly selects five coins.

The cent amount of Cecil’s selection is an even number

I honestly have no idea how to go about setting this one up. There are over 360,000 combinations, and I honestly have no idea where to start!

Comment: Hint: Cecil either selected 0 odd coins, 2 odd coins, or 4 odd coins.

Comment: For those of us not in your corner of the world, what are these denominations worth?

Comment: This is a multiset problem. The simple version of multiset is the usual $n$ take $k$. In multisets you have $n$ take $k_i$ for $i$ in a set of objects, here coins.

Comment: Quarter = 25 cents, dime = 10 cents, nickel = 5 cents, penny = 1 cent

Comment: Have you tried to implement grixor's hint?

Comment: Yes, I am still confused on setting it up. When I tried it like that, I still do not get the correct answer in the book...

Comment: @Steberz Could you show your work and what the book gives so that we can help you further?

Answer (score 2):

I guess I'll go ahead and give my solution.

The cent amount of Cecil’s selection is an even number when Cecil either selected 0 odd coins, 2 odd coins, or 4 odd coins. Since there are 7 even coins (the dimes) and 8 odd coins (the rest), the total number of ways to do this is:
$${7\choose 5} + {7\choose 3}{8\choose 2} + {7\choose 1}{8\choose 4} = 1491. $$

Comment: This is what I ended up with, but there is something I am doing wrong, because I am not getting 1491. Are you plugging the numbers over top of each other into this formula? (7/5) = 7!(7-5)! Or is there something wrong with the formula?

Comment: @Steberz The formula $$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}$$ so $$\binom{7}{5} = \frac{7!}{5!2!} = 21$$